# bison end of file

Tags: yacc, bison, lex, eof

If I forget to put an empty line at the end of any of my files my program gets a syntax error. The problem is my grammar expects a newline to end the current line. Since a newline doesn't exist bison generates a syntax error because it does not finish the rule.

How do I solve this? I tried making `<<EOF>>` return `MY_EOF` BUT when I do that lex crashes a horrible death. I guess there's code in its default EOF that I am not calling. I have no idea what functions they may be. Using EOF create the error `symbol EOF is used, but is not defined as a token and has no rules`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use a flex EOF rule to append a newline to the input:

```
<<EOF>> { static int once = 0; return once++ ? 0 : '\n' }
```

Comment: Note that if you want to do this in a re-entrant lexer, you must instead use `{ static int once = 0; return (once = !once) ? NEWLINE : 0; }` since otherwise the first file will prevent newlines being recognized on any future invocations.

Comment: @Hach-Que Good point - in that case, use: `{ if( !yyextra->eof ) { yyextra->eof = true; return NEWLINE; } else { yyterminate(); } }` and add an 'eof' field to your context.

Comment: When will we having multiple EOF ?

Comment: @AnkurGautam: If, after getting `EOF`, you reset the input (with `yyrestart` or `yy_scan_string` or similar), you can start reading again, and will later get another `EOF`

Answer (score 7):

In your lex file

```
#define yyterminate() return token::END
```

In your yacc file

```
%token END 0 "end of file"
```

Comment: I havent seen token:: before, are you using the C++ version? I had to change it to return MY_END But %token MY_END 0 "end of file" get me the warning `./test.y:90.11-75: warning: rule never reduced because of conflicts: $accept: program "end of file"`. It seems to work but i am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 3):

In fact to catch end of file in lex|flex you can use the `yywrap()` function which is called by lexical analyzer if end of the input file is reached.

this solution is available by both lex and flex.the callback of `yywrap()` indicates the `EOF`so you can reimplement this function and inject the work you need to do at the end of your input stream.

Comment: @blueshift No i didn't misspel yywarp, it is the macro, automatically called when we reach the end of the current buffer it returns 1 when there is no buffer to read or 0 if there is

Comment: I use flex and have `yywrap()` but no `yywarp()`. Are you sure?

Comment: @blueshift OMG am sorry i didn't get the point from the beginning it is yywrap()

Answer (score 1):

Previous works fine for me.

If you use C Bizon (not C++), just use END for token::END and in yacc file  `%token END`

Had another issue after that, if the macros return not YY_NULL, it never terminates (infinite loop)

It can be solved like this:

```
bool term = false;
#define yyterminate() return (term = !term)?END : YY_NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to restructure your grammar to not need a newline at the end.  As long as your language allows blank lines (usually the case), you can write your grammar using newline as a line *separator* rather than a line *terminator*

```
input: line | input '\n' line ;
line: /* empty */
    | ... various other rules ...
```

Now if you *do* have a newline at the end of the input, this gets treated as a blank line after that newline, which is probably fine.